# Resource of the general ellipse equation

Tags: reference-request, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

What I found so far is following equations [General Quadratic Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse):
$$AX^2+BXY+CY^2+DX+EY+F=0 $$

Semi-major/minor axis Equation:
$$a, b = \frac{1}{B^2 - 4AC} \sqrt{2 \left(AE^2 + CD^2 - BDE + \left(B^2 - 4AC\right) F\right)\left((A + C) \pm \sqrt{(A - C)^2 + B^2}\right)} 
$$

Coordinates of the center:
$$  x_\circ  = \frac{2CD - BE}{B^2 - 4AC} $$
$$  y_\circ  = \frac{2AE - BD}{B^2 - 4AC} $$

Angle of rotation:
$$\Theta = \begin{cases}
                \arctan\left(\frac{1}{B}\left(C - A - \sqrt{(A - C)^2 + B^2}\right)\right)
                                           & \text{for } B \ne 0 \\
                                         0 & \text{for } B = 0,\ A < C \\
                90^\circ = \frac{\pi}{2}^c & \text{for } B = 0,\ A > C \\
              \end{cases}$$

But where can I find a resource (best would be a book) of this formulas? Is there a book with these general quadratic equations for ellipses?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to your tags.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. Hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

Comment: @amd  Are you pointing to "Protter & Morrey - College Calculus with Analytic Geometry, 1970"? Are these equations in this book? Is there also a ebook or a successor of this book?

Comment: For ellipses in particular, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse or derive the formulas yourself. The calculations are tedious, but not difficult.